Do Baptists say God has a soul?
The question is: According to Baptists, does God have a soul?
Understandably, the answer will have to incorporate the Baptist definition of 'soul' and, if yes, whether it differs from the 'human soul'.
I apologize for the phrasing of the 'title'. The original was being wrongly resisted as a duplicate by the bot.
Related: What does Lutheranism say about God's soul?, A question for Roman Catholicism about the soul of God?, According to Eastern Orthodoxy does God have a soul?, What is the Methodist position on God's soul?, Does God have a soul according to Presbyterians?, Do Anglicans think God has a soul?, Do Pentecostals teach that God has a soul?

The Bible speaks of man and animals as "having souls".  It also speaks of men and animals not just having a soul but as "being a soul".  The Bible always uses "soul" in the context of things that have a physical body and need breath to keep alive. In the KJV, in the OT every occurance of "soul" is a translation from the Hebrew word "nephesh", 5315 in Strong's Concordance, which says it is derived from "naphash", to breathe.  Job 41:21 nephesh is translated as "breath", "His breath kindleth coals".  A nephesh, a soul, then, might be described as a thing which usually needs to breathe in order to live, i.e. a physical being, a creature. A nephesh depends on its environment in order to keep alive the body for which it was created/ which was created for it. While the body is alive the soul causes the body to breathe.  When the body stops breathing it is because the soul has departed from the body.
The Hebrew word for "spirit" is "ruwach", Strong's 7307. It is likened to the breath itself, or to the wind, or to the life itself.  God then is a spirit.  He has no dependancy on anything outside of himself. God is (like) the wind, the life, the breath, the spirit.  "Ruwach" is used many times of God, also of men, but (as far as I can see) only once of animals in Ecclesiastes 3:21, "Who knows if the spirit of man goes up and the spirit of the beast goes down into the earth?"
Not surprisingly then, in the Baptist circles I know of, I never hear of God having a "soul".  Even though when refering to creatures the words spirit and soul can be used rather interchangeably, I only hear God has a spirit, or rather more often God is Spirit. And like many reformed Baptists I read a fair amount from reformed Presbyterians, and I never hear of them speaking of God as having a soul either. God is Spirit, he has no soul, and he needs no soul.  He is not dependant on anything, such as air to breath, outside of himself.
Postscript
The OP draws attention to the word "soul" being applied to the LORD in Leviticus 26.  This is in verses 11 and 30.  In this chapter verses 1-13 speak of the consequences of obedience which will include "my soul shall not abhor you", v11.  Verses 14-43 speak of the consequences of disobedience: because "if your soul abhor my judgements" v15 ...then... "my soul shall abhor you", v30. And all the judgements I shall put upon them will be "because their soul abhorred my judgements" v43.
It can be seen there is a reciprocation in the passage.  It looks as if the word "soul" is used to emphasise the reciprocal nature of the LORD's actions: his actions against them were provoked by them; they were therefore just, fair and right.
It could be argued that "soul" is used of God here anthropomorphically.. similar to when the Bible speaks of "the arm of the LORD", or "the eyes of the LORD are in every place, beholding the evil and the good, Proverbs 15:3, when God neither has literal arms nor eyes.  But this need not be insisted on.  The similarity between soul and spirit is so near that it could be argued that it isn't entirely wrong to say God has a soul.
Really, it all boils down to usual usage: "nephesh" is used around 500 times for creatures in the OT, mostly of humans.  It is not usual for the Bible to say God has a soul, and where it is so used I believe the preference amongst Baptists would likely be (though admittedly I cannot prove it) that the term is being used anthropomorphically for emphasis of the reciprical response God will show towards the children of Israel if they abhor him in their soul: "If your soul abhor my judgements... my soul shall abhor you".
Thankfully, the chapter does not end there, but continues "And yet for all that...", Leviticus 26:44.

What about versus such as Leviticus 26:11 and a few others. How are those explained?

@MikeBorden. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/56213/11555

@MikeBorden  As the last line in the answer points out, the verses following give the meaning. Lev 26:30 - "my soul will abhor you" is Hebrew idiom for the extreme disgust God has for idol worship, as explained in detail in the one answer in the link provided in the comment above.

@AndrewShanks  In that link is a comment giving the thought that when God is spoken of with regard to “my soul” it means deepest depths, not that God has a soul. Your point about anthropomorphic meaning is valid. We all know that when the Bible speaks of God as having hair like wool, and a beard etc., that is not to be taken literally.  Anne

Excellent answer. This agrees with my own personal study on the subject. Up-voted +1.


And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: (Gen 1:26a)

Man being in the image of God, with Body, Soul and Spirit, necessitates that God has these parts also.
Man also has power, presence, knowledge and intelligence - by which we recognise the omnipotence, omniscience and wisdom of God.

God is omnipresent.  Is this, then, necessitated in man?  Please expand your answer to explain why the soul of God is communicated in creation while other attributes are not.

Thank you @Mike.

God has a body?  I'm still unclear.  This does not sound like any Baptist position I've yet heard.

Brother Michael, As a Baptist myself, I think this answer suffers from an almost imperceptible dash of terminological inexactitude.

@MikeBorden : 1 Timothy 3:16 KJV
And without controversy great is the mystery of godliness: God was manifest in the flesh, justified in the Spirit, seen of angels, preached unto the Gentiles, believed on in the world, received up into glory.
